# git-log with an "OR" clause - or - how to merge git-log outputs?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I'm currently trying to cherry-pick a feature from the trunk of an OSS project into a fork.  Both repositories use git and I have the trunk imported into the fork as a branch so it should make things nice and easy.

The approach I'm taking is to try to cherry-pick all relevant commits from one branch to another as it's not possible for me to just do a straight merge: there are too many things that have diverged.

In order to generate the list of commits I should start with to cherry-pick I've identified two `git-log` commands to run:

```
git log --branch project-trunk **/*Foo*
```

This is intended to give me the log for any file with the word "Foo" in it on the `project-trunk` branch.  This is a pretty good starting point but I've found that there are other commits that are relevant: luckily they usually have an identifying work in the commit log.  So to find these I'm using:

```
git log --branch project-trunk --grep Bar
```

This gives me any logs on the branch `project-trunk` which contain the work "Bar".

The problem is that I really need a master list, ordered chronologically containing the union of both those commands.  I've read the `git rev-list` manual but I can't see any way of doing what I want.

Is it possible to union two seperate conditions like this? And if not, is there a simple way to union the output of two `git-log` commands chronologically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got impatient and with a bit more playing around I came up with the following which seems to work:

```
(git rev-list --grep=Bar heads/project-trunk; git rev-list heads/project-trunk **/*Foo*) | git log --stdin --no-walk --reverse
```

If anyone can improve on it at all let me know!  Hope this helps someone else in the future...